# MSP430 I2C slave to generate PWM signal , master is R-pi3

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, code-composer

I need to code for a MSP430FR5969 launch pad that can generate PWM signal upto 100KHz, I want to control it with R-Pi3 over the I2C bus to send the Freq and duty cycle to the MSP430.
I am very new in coding MSP430, any help would be appreciate it.

thans

Answer (score 0):

I find the best approach is to look at the examples provided for this particular LaunchPad. You'll now find these under Resource Explorer.

Run the [PWM example](http://dev.ti.com/tirex/#/DevTool/MSP-EXP430FR5969/?link=Software%2FMSP430Ware%2FDevelopment%20Tools%2FMSP-EXP430FR5969%2FPeripheral%20Examples%2FDriver%20Library%2FExample%20Projects%2FTIMER_A%2Ftimer_a_ex1_pwmSingle) and get your head around what it's doing. This should be easy enough using the on-board LED.

Then run the [I2C example](http://dev.ti.com/tirex/#/DevTool/MSP-EXP430FR5969/?link=Software%2FMSP430Ware%2FDevelopment%20Tools%2FMSP-EXP430FR5969%2FPeripheral%20Examples%2FDriver%20Library%2FExample%20Projects%2FEUSCI_B_I2C) and get your head round what that's doing. You can connect it straight to the Pi, but a logic analyser will really help with this.

Peripheral setup is the hardest part of MSP430 coding. Once you get this right (or just copy it from an example) the code in between is normally much easier.